# Local LAN Server IIS Manager hosting .Net MVC Application stops working when IP address changes

Tags: asp.net, iis, hosting, lan

I have a MVC5 web application hosted on a LAN server using IIS Manager. we access this application from various office PC's on the network. However we are having issues where the server IP address keeps changing - we have debugged the router, changed it but nothing helps. When the server IP changes I need to physically change the binding and issue the new IP address - 
Is there a better to get around this problem?

Comment: Don't connect to your application via IP address. Have a domain named issued so that DNS takes care of it. And have your IT people figure out why the IP changes - that's not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: When the server IP changes I need to physically change the binding and issue the new IP address - What binding you are talking about?